# SocketAsyncEventArgs Encryption -- SSL vs. Custom Pre-Transmission Encryption

Tags: c#, sockets, encryption, ssl

I'm working on implementing a high-performance server using IOCP & SocketAsyncEventArgs.  From what I've read, getting SSL using this method is not "easy," as I've found you either need to implement SSL yourself, or somehow incorporate a NetworkStream using SSL into the model.

My question is, what would be the security and performance implications of incorporating a pre/post transmission encryption model, encrypting my transmitted byte array to the remote endpoint, then decrypting the byte array after recipience?

I'd love to implement SSL as I've seen "custom" encryption schemes cause a huge performance overhead on the server.

Any suggestions, pointers, or resources would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another nice aspect of using TLS is that it will automatically prevent [replay attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack). If you write your own pre-transport encryption and authentication mechanism, you will also need to include replay attack detection, which is additional work on your end.

As an alternatives to both pre-transport and TLS support, you could also do something like tunnel all your traffic through an SSH or TLS tunnel "outside" your application (calling `ssh -L` or `stunnel` to start some tunnels before starting your application), or configure IPSec between your endpoints. These are barriers to easy deployment, so they aren't to be taken lightly, but many system administrators are already familiar with SSH or TLS tunnels, and if it makes programming significantly easier in an otherwise good environment, it might be the solution of least annoyance.

Comment: I really would like to implement SSL but I do not see how it's possible with SocketAsyncEventArgs.  Thanks for the info!